# Using multiple node_modules

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, node-modules, package.json

In a React.js project I have 2 node_modules folders, one of them is in the root folder, and one of them is in the client folder.
The node_modules folder in the root folder is related to the server, and the node_modules folder in the client folder is related to the Front-End (React.js files).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYNRd.png)

My problem is that the dependencies I have imported and used in the React components don't recognize the packages in the node_modules folder which is in the client folder and try to read the dependencies from the node_modules folder which is in the root folder.

I have no idea about this problem.